# how to differentate pulsed Lasers simultanieously

Tags: c++, opencv

How do i diffentiate or track the pulsed laser spots simultaniously for different pulse . 
Basically we are trying to make a hunting Game so for that am the one  who is developing the Shooting algorithm. In that am using pulsed laser weapons for shooting and the pulses for different weapon are as follows i.e 20msec,50msec,100msec,130msec,160msec. etc..

So for this am using basler camera at 120fps ,Opencv, Qt C++ for doing this concept
1st i calculated how many frames might these lasers come and they are 3,6,10,14,18 consecutive frames for above mentioned pulses. using hough circle transformation am able to find the laser hit detection spot

```
 cvtColor(image,greyscale,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(greyscale,greyscale,Size(9,9),5,10);
    threshold(greyscale,greyscale,10,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    HoughCircles(greyscale, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, greyscale.rows / 8, 50, 5, 0,100);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);

        circle(greyscale, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 8);

//Here center.x and center.y is actual x,y position of circle
}
```

so am able to get the x,y of laser hit spot.Now How can i track these such that i should identify that wt is the laser which was shot at run time and At run time all 5 lasers are also fired . so my program should be in such a way that 
it has to detect which laser is fired even when multi lasers are shot .how can i find this i tried going frame by frame and checking the circle x,y and with prev frame am comparing if it matches am incrementing a variable untill next non_detected frame or non matched x,y and actually it works when all are firing one after the other.But my app should work even if all are firing at once . For this i have only one opening that is identifying and seperating by "pulse" of that laser .i.e i have to see how long that perticular stays on when fired in run time when all others are also firing simultanieously . so i have searched for it in online but no proper help. and even am new to  computer vision. Please any help ?
Thank You

Comment: Is the x,y location where the pulsed laser  is incident of any use to you? Do you know where each laser is incident upon?

Comment: x,y are used to find the coordinates of center of the circle and later ill scale these x, y and send the data to  Actual Game exe . and am able to know how many lasers are been shot at run time as circles.size() will say how many circles are detected for that frame.